# (React and Redux) Problem with adding items to the shopping cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, shopping-cart

I am following a tutorial, where we are building a shopping cart, which is still unfinished, but I would like to solve this problem before continuing in the tutorial.

The thing is, that when I try to add any item to the cart, the cart is still saying me, that my shopping cart is empty. You can notice in the url of this picture below, that I have added the item with id number 1 to the shopping cart and quantity (qty) is also 1. [image]

But the shopping cart should not respond this kind of message after adding an item into it. At this stage, in which the code is, the response should be just a blank page.

This didn´t work yet when I was trying to console.log the cartItems - it was an empty array for me, but the instructor was receiving the data about the products, which were added to cart. So that might be a clue.

Please take a look at the following files and let me know, if You will be able to see any hint or a solution.

CartScreen.js -

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col, ListGroup, Image, Form, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { addToCart } from '../actions/cartActions'


function CartScreen({ match, location, history }) {
    const productId = match.params.div
    const qty = location.search ? Number(location.search.split('=')[1]) : 1
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart)
    const { cartItems } = cart
    
    useEffect(() =>{
        if(productId){
            dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty))
        }    
    }, [dispatch, productId, qty])
    return (
        <Row>
            <Col md={8}>
             <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
             {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
                 <Message variant='info'>
                     Your cart is empty <Link to='/'>Go Back</Link>
                 </Message>
             ) : (
                 <listGroup variant='flush'>

                 </listGroup>
             )}
            </Col>

            <Col md={4}>
                
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
}

export default CartScreen
```

cartActions.js -

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants'

export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
   const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

   dispatch({
      type:CART_ADD_ITEM,
      payload:{
          product:data._id,
          name:data.name,
          image:data.image,
          price:data.price,
          countInStock:data.countInStock,
          qty
    }
   })
   localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}
```

cartReducers.js -

```
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants'

export const cartReducer = (state={cartItems:[] }, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
       case CART_ADD_ITEM:
           const item = action.payload
           const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => x.product === item.product)
           
           if(existItem){
               return{
                   ...state,
                   cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x =>
                     x.product === existItem.product ? item : x)
               }
           }else{
              return{
                  ...state,
                  cartItems:[...state.cartItems, item]
              }
           }
       default:
           return state
    }
}
```

cartConstants.js -

```
export const CART_ADD_ITEM = 'CART_ADD_ITEM'
export const CART_REMOVE_ITEM = 'CART_REMOVE_ITEM'
```

store.js -

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { productListReducer, productDetailsReducer } from './reducers/productReducers'
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers'

const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList:productListReducer,
    productDetails:productDetailsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer, 
})

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ?
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : []

const initialState = {
    cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage }
}

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store
```

ProductScreen.js -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import { listProductDetails } from '../actions/productActions'

function ProductScreen({ match, history }) {
  const[qty, setQty] = useState(1)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails
 
  useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(listProductDetails(match.params.id))
  },[dispatch, match])

  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    history.push(`/cart/${match.params.id}?qty=${qty}`)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/" className="btn btn-light my-3">
        Go Back
      </Link>
      {loading ?
         <Loader/>
         : error
             ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
         :(
          <Row>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
          </Col>
  
          <Col md={3}>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
              </ListGroup.Item>
  
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Rating
                  value={product.rating}
                  text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                  color={"#f8e825"}
                />
              </ListGroup.Item>
  
              <ListGroup.Item>Price: ${product.price}</ListGroup.Item>
  
              <ListGroup.Item>Description: {product.description}</ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Col>
  
          <Col md={3}>
            <Card>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Price:</Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
  
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Status:</Col>
                    <Col>
                      {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock"}
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>

                {product.countInStock > 0 && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Row>
                      <Col>Qty</Col>
                      <Col xs='auto' className='my-1'>
                        <Form.Control
                          as="select"
                          value={qty}
                          onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
                        >
                          {
                          
                            [...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                              <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                                {x + 1}
                              </option>
                            ))
                          }

                        </Form.Control>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}


  
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Button
                    onClick={addToCartHandler}
                    className="btn-block"
                    disabled={product.countInStock == 0}
                    type="button"
                  >
                    Add to Cart
                  </Button>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
         )

      }

      
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code you've shown so far. It's in the code where you add the item to the cart and then navigate to the cart. I suspect you're dispatching the action to add the item to the cart and you're not waiting for it to resolve. Dispatching an action is a promise and is asynchronous. You have to wait until it resolves, unlike with commits, which are synchronous. This would explain why you reach the cart page while the cart is still empty.

Comment: Hello, I have added two additional files to this post - store.js and ProductScreen.js. Do You think, that the solution to the problem might be hidden somewhere in there? Thank You very much for the hints, but I am not sure how to translate this knowledge into the code itself.

Comment: the index.js was untouched, when we were building the cart, but maybe it will be helpful to you.

index.js -

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'
import './index.css';
import './bootstrap.min.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the error :

```
const productId = match.params.div
```

it should be "id" not div

```
const productId = match.params.id
```

Comment: I am really grateful to You, dear sir. Thank You very much for Your remarkable observation. This has solved my problem, thus I can continue in the course and that is truly amazing, because I am looking forward to build another parts of the store. :-)

Comment: @JanKoci good luck. do not rush it, that is why you make this mistake

Answer (score 0):

In cartReducers.js you are using `state.cartItems` when updating the state and in the CartScreen.js you are using `const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart)`.

I can't see the index.js but it looks like you may have an inconsistency in your state names. Suggestion: `useSelector(state => state.cartItems)`

Comment: Greetings, thanks for the help. If I attempt to change that code, then I am getting the following error -
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'cartItems' of 'cart' as it is undefined.

The instructor is using const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart) and it is working for him.

Comment: I have updated this post with 2 new files - store.js and HomeScreen.js :-)

Comment: the index.js was untouched, when we were building the cart, but maybe it will be helpful to you.

index.js -

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'
import './index.css';
import './bootstrap.min.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();